# Sliding in Warface

Tags: warface

I've been playing Warface lately but it's not out in English yet, so I've been playing the Russian version. The problem with this is that everything is in Russian, including the controls and i can't figure out how i can slide.

Can anyone tell me the button to slide in Warface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> to rush, and while rushing press <kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> to slide.

Comment: Wonderful, works like a charm :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)